# How do I display dynamic data on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to build a helpdesk page.

I list the categories and the subject under each category on the left side of the page. I want to display the article related to the subject (and id) to be displayed on the content `div` when the user click on the subject in the left menu.

The categories display in the accordion header and the subjects display when the accordions are opened, but when I click on the subject, no article display.

My current code:

```
<?php

require_once('Path/To/connect_pdo.php');

// Prepare a select statement to retrieve all categories
$stmtCategories = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM `categories`");
$stmtCategories->execute();
$categories = $stmtCategories->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Prepare a select statement to retrieve all articles
$stmtArticles = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, catid, subject, content FROM `articles`");
$stmtArticles->execute();
$articles = $stmtArticles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Close the database connection
$conn = null;
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

<title>Knowledgebase</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        display: flex;
    }

    .left-menu {
        width: 30%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        padding: 20px;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        max-height: calc(100vh - 100px); /* Adjust the value based on your layout */
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .content {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .menu-link {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .menu-link:hover {
        color: #1e73be;
        
    }

    .accordion-header {
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    }

    .accordion-header:hover {
        background-color: #eaeaea;
        color: #333;
    }

    .accordion-header.active {
        background-color: #eaeaea;
        color: #333;
    }

    .accordion-header i {
        transition: transform 0.3s;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    .accordion-header.active i {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .accordion-header:hover i {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    .accordion-content {
        display: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .active {
        display: block;
    }

    .category-name {
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }

    .subject-name {
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .no-bullet {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .icon {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: #000;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .menu-link {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
const articles = <?php echo json_encode($articles); ?>;

function toggleAccordion(id) {
    const content = document.getElementById('category-' + id);
    content.classList.toggle('active');
}

function displayArticleContent(id) {
    const articleContent = document.getElementById('article-content');
    const article = articles.find(article => article.id === id);

    if (article) {
        articleContent.innerHTML = `<h2>${article.subject}</h2>${article.content}`;
    } else {
        articleContent.innerHTML = '<p style="text-align: center;">Please select a question.</p>';
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="left-menu">
<h2>Categories</h2>
<ul class="no-bullet">
    <?php
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<div class="accordion-header" onclick="toggleAccordion(' . $category['id'] . ')"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> <span class="category-name">' . $category['name'] . '</span></div>';
        echo '<ul id="category-' . $category['id'] . '" class="accordion-content">';
        foreach ($articles as $article) {
            if ($article['catid'] == $category['id']) {
                echo '<li><a class="menu-link" href="#" onclick="displayArticleContent(' . $article['id'] . ')">' . $article['subject'] . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content" id="article-content">
<p style="text-align: center;">Please select a question.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe strict equality cause it ? by the way you should use ajax for this case especially, without it you pump all articles in single request, eating unnecessary data/brandwidth

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed to ajax and all working now.